Error while loading experience editor in Sitecore
I am working on a Sitecore JSS application with Next.js and the problem is that the data is rendered correctly on localhost but experience editor is not loading, and bigger problem is that data is rendered on experience editor but it still loads and gives server error.
I checked console and this is the main error..
Pasting Console image if helps, well it shows hydration error but i am sure that code is clean.
Error 1: reading browser
locating error
Real problem related to Experience Editor ribbon

I found a solution, there was problem with certificates, hence i needed to remove older certificates and add new certificates.
you can follow this link:
https://sitecorecorner.wordpress.com/2020/08/09/fix-xconnect-certificate-errors/
